# What is SMBUS and why is it disabled in my BIOS?

Tags: motherboard, bios

My motherboard is an HP P4SD, and in the BIOS I found `SMBUS` in the Security tab.  There is also something like "Device security."

There's a list and the value of `SMBUS` is "Hidden."  That means that no Operating System will know about it (the device is disabled).

What is `SMBUS` and why is it disabled?  How can I use this thing?

**UPDATE**
[After this](https://superuser.com/questions/318541/black-screen-while-pc-boots) ive restarted BIOS settings and SMBUS was disabled by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The SMBus is the "System Management Bus".

It's an Intel-defined chipset feature for reporting things like fan speeds, motherboard temperatures, serial/model numbers, etc., to the OS.

Often there will be a monitoring utility provided by the motherboard manufacturer that takes advantage of the SMBus.  You can also use it with programs like [SpeedFan](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php).

More info is available at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Bus) and [SMBus.org](http://smbus.org/).

As for *why* it's disabled, that's hard to say; maybe someone disabled it, or possibly it's disabled because Asus doesn't offer a monitoring utility for that board, so they turn it off by default to preserve resources.

Comment: Windows installed it. Cool, it works!